# How to ensure that content is formatted properly with AutoScroll on a windows form when the controls are programmatically added

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I have a windows form that is populated entirely by programmatically added controls with vb.net. It essentially creates a table of textboxes and buttons. You specify how many columns and rows of boxes that you would like to appear at form load. You also have the option of inserting rows and columns from inside the form as well.

The problem occurs when you would like to insert rows or columns, the autoscroll appears to be interfering with the programmatic placement of the rows or columns. All of the controls report the proper position on the form, but you can clearly see that there are large gaps appearing where the newly placed textboxes reside, only when the scrollbar begins to appear. To compound the issue, the displacement of textboxes appears to increase exponentially with each subsequent textbox addition. Again, the left and top properties all report back normal.

Another strange thing is that if you specify a high amount of rows and columns at form load, no problem with the formatting occurs and the form scrolls properly.

Any Ideas?

**Edit:** Below is a code snippet of part of the code that adds the cells to create a new column to the right of the right most column. I also want to state that more controls are placed properly when you maximize the window, but you still encounter the problem, it is just delayed, this is how I know that the code is not the problem.

```
For counter2 As Integer = 0 To importednumberofrows - 1
        addCells(counter2) = New RichTextBox
        With addCells(counter2)
            .Name = "TextBox" & counter2.ToString() & "." & importednumberofcolumns.ToString()
            .Height = 60
            .Width = 200
            .Left = (importednumberofcolumns * 200) + 40
            If importedheader = vbYes Then
                .Top = ((counter2) * 60) + 100
            Else
                .Top = ((counter2) * 60) + 40
            End If
            .Text = "TextBox" & counter2.ToString() & "." & importednumberofcolumns.ToString()
        End With
        Me.Controls.Add(addCells(counter2))
    Next
```

Comment: Perhaps you should use a `TableLayoutPanel` to contain all the other controls, thus you don't have to worry about positioning at all.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much jmcilhinney, that did the trick. I ported the code over to import the controls onto TableLayoutPanels, removing the positioning and it now scrolls properly.